# How to set vscode to display the number of selected lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Who knows how to set vscode to display the number of selected lines? Just like NotePad++, when we select many lines, we can see how many lines selected in the lower right corner, thanks!

Comment: you need to find/write an extension that updates a status bar field. One of the demo extensions shows the number of lines https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/extending-workbench#status-bar-item

Comment: Thank you very much!@rioV8, people who need could find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=selected%20lines&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance) , this extension's name is "Selected Lines Count".

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Surely, you can find an extension. Till now, you can see in the **Status Bar**, how many characters you have selected. Take a look, at some extensions [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=selected%20lines&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).

[image]

Comment: You should say what extension you found that shows the number of selected lines so people know.

Comment: In the link, you can find many. For example, [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanBackes.lines) one.

Comment: Thank you very much for your guidance, @Mark, this is my first time to use Stack overflow, I will pay attention to it in the future. This extension's name is "Selected Lines Count", you can find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=selected%20lines&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance)

Answer (score 78):

### Try this extension: [Selected Lines Count](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gurumukhi.selected-lines-count)

[image: demo]

Without an extension, you have to resort to a workaround: use the command *Add Cursors to Line Ends* and observe the selection count.  The default shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> (i, not L).

[image]

Comment: I found that shift-alt and then drag selection is more practical then select and then shift-alt-i

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + [Up | Down] enables a multi-line cursor for me (Shift + Alt copies a line). You can use Ctrl + Alt + [Up | Down] to count lines, which is nearly the same as Shift + Alt + I, except that you don't have to make a selection first.